# How to override default block template in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, deprecated, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I am using Twentytwentytwo theme which is completely built in this new block structure.
I created a plugin and I have added my custom post type with some custom fields to it. Now I want to create my own template to display single post of this post type with custom field values in it.

If I try usual approach in my template file like this:

```
get_header();
// some content output
get_footer();
```

It will give me an error that get_header() is deprecated now:

> Deprecated: File Theme without header.php is deprecated since version 3.0.0 with no alternative available. Please include a header.php template in your theme. in /home/c/cv55478/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5579

And same with footer.php

That's how I use this template in my plugin:

```
// customize template for single program page
add_filter( 'single_template', 'ozzsf_single_program_template' );
function ozzsf_single_program_template( $single_template ) {
    global $post;

    if ( $post->post_type == 'program' ) {
        $program_template = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'templates/single-program.php';

        if ( file_exists( $program_template ) ) {
            $single_template = $program_template;
        }
    }

    return $single_template;
}
```

I tried to copy twentytwentytwo/templates/single.html to my plugin and use this template instead but it does not get compiled as it does in the theme.

Also, WooCommerce of latest version uses old approach with php templates and get_header() but it does not get any warnings or errors. How come?

Comment: I know it's been a while, but have you figured it out? I am stuck on the same problem.

Comment: @AlexSchörg Nope. This is my pet project so I just postponed it to better times.